# I am not sure about the usage of .next in python

Tags: python

Can anyone explain the usage of *next* in this case to me?

```
class Solution:

    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
        carry = 0
        root = n = ListNode(0)
        while l1 or l2 or carry:
            v1 = v2 = 0
            if l1:
                v1 = l1.val
                l1 = l1.next
            if l2:
                v2 = l2.val
                l2 = l2.next
            carry, val = divmod(v1+v2+carry, 10)
            n.next = ListNode(val)
            n = n.next
        return root.next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you would need to look at the class definition of ListNode, as .next is just an object attribute as far as Python is concerned, not a special language construct of some kind.

Since the code looks like a linked list, it would be sensible for this to contain a reference to the next ListNode in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The method next() is used when a file is used as an iterator, typically in a loop, the next() method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises StopIteration when EOF is hit.